Can a subscriber update a FeatureParameterInteger of second-gen managed package?
We plan to use the Salesforce Feature Management App with our second-generation managed package. We have to set a FeatureParameterInteger (LmoToSubscriber): Allowed Active Employees and another FeatureParameterInteger (SubscriberToLmo): Current Active Employees.
We are concerned about the "Current Active Employees" parameter. Is there any way our subscribers can modify the value of this feature parameter as it is SubscriberToLmo (in case they find out the API name of this feature)? Can this be directly modified in subscriber org from the Dev console or any unmanaged class?
Also, what is the maximum length allowed for this FeatureParameterInteger? Is it the same Number (18,0)?
This question was raised when we saw the "Components Available in Second-Generation Managed Packages" page for "Feature Parameter Integer" which says,
Both Package Developer and Subscriber Can Edit

Value (When Data Flow Direction is set to Subscriber to LMO)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_feature_parameter_integer

What exactly is the concern that you have with that value? As per the documentation you have shared, yes that value would be able to be edited within the subscriber org. However, that is also the point of having Subscriber to LMO configured integers. If you have concerns about a subscriber being able to modify that attribute, then it sounds like you are using it in a way in which it is not designed.

Hi @CallumMacErlich we have not yet used this approach but planning to do it to enable a record limit for one of our managed package objects. Our concern is if any way a subscriber can edit it. Do we have to make any validation/restriction to not allow subscriber updating it outside our managed package?

If you're looking to enforce it on the subscriber, wouldn't it be better to use the LMO to Subscriber direction and then enforce this using a Trigger or Record Triggered Flow in your managed package? If you want to know how many records the subscriber has, then you'd want to use a separate integer for this than the one that you're using to set the limit, but that is the only use case I can see that you would want the data flowing in that direction.

As I mentioned in the post "We have to set a FeatureParameterInteger (LmoToSubscriber): Allowed Active Employees and another FeatureParameterInteger (SubscriberToLmo): Current Active Employees." We have 2 params, one to set the limit and the other to get the record count from the subscriber. We will use Apex code to update the subscriber side param "Current Active Employees" in our managed package. But is there any way Subscriber can reset this counter to 0 or less record by their access anyway (outside our managed package code)?

You're worried about a customer putting their car on blocks and throwing it in reverse to roll back the odometer--right?
I would just bake into your package some logic that compares the actual value of the number of active employees (by querying number of active users, etc.) with your LMOtoSubscriber FP. If the former exceeds the latter then you can throw an exception to the user.
Meanwhile, you can still set your SubscribertoLMO FP using that same number so you can see from the PBO when customers are close to exceeding their capacity so you can proactively reach out.
